# Disabling pause and skipping into HLS content in and HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, http-live-streaming

We're building a system to serve archive content through an HTML5 player using HLS.

Part of the spec on the player is to simulate a live broadcast of the content.

Is it possible to set a start point on playback with the HTML5 player on iOS and Android and either disable pause, or catch the resume command and skip forward by the duration paused to simulate that effect?

Further is it possible to disable scrubbing on archive HLS content?

Comment: (eg in HTML) you could disable the regular player controls and present your own. Trapping the play event would let you adjust the currentTime to anything you needed